# Embedding Twitch Player is working in fiddle but not in local html-file

Tags: javascript, embedding, twitch

im trying to embed a twitch player to my local html-file. 
The Code can be seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GACZWRWOSZ9M. If i create my file locally with the same exact code, the buttons and the event listeners are not working.

I red that this might be happening because the first script hasnt finished loading by the time the twitch player is instantiated and tried something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAD1GO4LW13C. But this wasnt working either.

I will add two pictures to compare the console output.

The first picture is the output from the first link: https://ibb.co/dGv7j9v

The second picture is the output of my local html-file: https://ibb.co/NtLwZKK

You can see on the second picture that the "ready" and "play" events are not being fired and that the underline channel properties are empty.

It would be really cool if someone could tell me why this isnt working locally. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a perfect answer but it looks like what's happening is when you open it from a file, the URL starts with "file://" and doesn't set some things that would otherwise be set if you used a regular web protocol like "http://"

It seems the library you're using can't handle that situation. I tried it on a local webserver and it did work just fine there so I think your code is fine, just needs to be accessed over http or https.

Comment: seems to be an issue with crome. if i open the file in microsoft edge i dont get this particular error